# Send current location of the device to an another user

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, azure-mobile-services

I am trying to make an Windows phone app. I want to know is it possible to send current location of the device to an another user. I am using azure mobile services.
 If possible can you please provide me some resources. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The method to get the current location is through use of

```
Geoposition geoposition = await geolocator.GetGeopositionAsync(
            maximumAge: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
            timeout: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)
            );
```

But best is to read up on how to use this correctly inside an app from the MSDN documentation here 
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206956(v=vs.105).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206956%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)